# The "&" with no parameters

Tags: elixir

I have this:

```
    case test123(&(:some_module.test456(789))) do
      # ...
    end
```

An error:

```
invalid args for &, expected an expression in the format of &Mod.fun/arity, 
&local/arity or a capture containing at least one argument as &1, 
got: :some_module.test456(789)
```

However, I don't have a parameter to pass into it and previously it was merely

```
 fn(_) -> :some_module.test456(789) end
```

How to fix it? Switch back to "fn"?

Answer (score 10):

The `&` syntax cannot be used to create such anonymous functions because the compiler can't know whether you wanted to create a 0 or 1 or 2 or more arity function. You'll have to keep using `fn(_) -> :some_module.test456(789) end`.

Comment: `fn(_) -> ...` expects one parameter. `&` can also be used to form an anonymous function that does the same regardless of what is passed as its one parameter. Perhaps you meant `fn -> :some_module.test456(789) end` ?

Comment: How would you create the equivalent of `fn(_) -> :some_module.test456(789) end` using `&`? I believe that function is exactly what OP wants and I don't know of any way to achieve that with `&`.

Comment: It's not pretty lol, for example, `&(hd ["return this", &1])`. But I think OP wanted arity of zero, which I don't think can be achieved with `&`.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I did think of `&elem({&1, "return this"}, 1)` but that looks like a huge hack, but you're right, this is technically possible by calling a function which throws away the argument.